# shared_ptr and unique_ptr Constructors in Lippman's C++ Primer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

Among other things, the chapter (12) on Dynamic Memory in C++ Primer (5th Edition) mentions a couple of constructors on `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` that I couldn't find online. I am writing this question to clarify the existence of these two constructors. If they do exist, specific questions about them have been asked below

1. `shared_ptr<T> p(p2, d)`: 
        `p` is a copy of the `shared_ptr` `p2`, except that `p` uses the
       callable object `d` in place of `delete`

   I don't get the portion on the deleter here: `p` will point to the
   same underlying object as `p2`, and the reference count gets
   incremented by 1. While defining `p2`, one would have already
   specified a custom deleter, or used the default `delete`. What is
   the point of specifying a new deleter here?
2. `unique_ptr<T, D> u(d)`: Null `unique_ptr` that points to objects of
   type `T` that uses `d` (which must be an object of type `D`) in
   place of `delete`

   Now, this makes complete sense. However, I found a similar
   constructor for `shared_ptr`, but nothing for `unique_ptr`

Here are the resources I looked into:

`shared_ptr`:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/
2. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

`unique_ptr`:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/
2. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr

Just wanted to confirm whether they are legitimate or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 20.7.2.2 The only constructors for `shared_ptr` I see that accept a deleter are ones that accept raw pointers or `nullptr_t`.

For `unique_ptr`, from 20.7.1.2 it looks like you could concoct a deleter type for which the underlying typedef would be another `unique_ptr`, but in order to retain the correct semantics you would have to take ownership of the object itself, so changing the deleter wouldn't necessarily be a problem (for example you might change it from immediate delete to return-to-pool on the fly).